# Xcode [objective-c] cocos2d Unresponsive buttons in CCScrollLayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, cocos2d-iphone

I had a button that is used to change the scene of the game, I put it inside a CCSCrollLayer and it stopped working, here's my code:

```
    // create a blank layer for page 1
    CCLayer *pageOne = [[CCLayer alloc] init];

    // create a button for page 1
    CCMenuItem *level1 = [CCMenuItemImage
                          itemFromNormalImage:@"level_skatepark_icon.png" selectedImage:nil
                          target:self selector:@selector(level1Tapped:)];
    level1.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2 - 28);

    // add button to page 1 layer
    [pageOne addChild:level1];



    // now create the scroller and pass-in the pages (set widthOffset to 0 for fullscreen pages)
    CCScrollLayer *scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: pageOne,pageTwo,pageThree,pageFour,nil] widthOffset: 150];

    // finally add the scroller to your scene
    [self addChild:scroller];
```

The listener:

```
- (void)level1Tapped:(id)sender {
    //Goto level SkatePark!
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How can i make he start working back again?

Comment: What do you mean with 'stopped working'? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add CCMenuItems directly to layer. Add them to CCMenu object and add this menu to the layer.